# How to share navigation drawer through multiple activities

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I've an issue with my navigation drawer, I want to share it through all the activities, but I've no idea of the way to do it.

If you have any ideas, it will help me for sure.

Here's my code:

**Main activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<Main_Content> Main_content;
private ListViewAdapter adapter;
ImageButton ConnectButton;
EditText iden_text, pass_text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Main_content = new ArrayList<>(); //Déclaration de la liste Main_content ou se trouveront les éléments de notre menu

    findViewById();
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    initDrawerLayout();


    ConnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if (iden_text.getText().toString().equals("admin") && pass_text.getText().toString().equals("admin"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vérification des données...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent Bienvenue = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Bienvenue.class);
                Bienvenue.putExtra("iden_text", iden_text.getText().toString());
                startActivity(Bienvenue);

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Identifiants incorrects", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        }
    } );
}

public void findViewById()
{
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    ConnectButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    iden_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    pass_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}


public void initDrawerLayout() {
    setListViewData();
    setListViewHeader();
    //Mount listview with adapter
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.item_listview, Main_content);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

public void setListViewHeader() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_listview, listView, false);
    listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
}

public void setListViewData() { //Liste afficher dans le menu
    Main_content.add(new Main_Content(R.mipmap.id_small,"Carte ID", "Nom Random"));
    Main_content.add(new Main_Content(R.mipmap.note_small, "Relevé de note", "Note"));
    Main_content.add(new Main_Content(R.mipmap.calendar, "Calendrier", "Jours"));
    Main_content.add(new Main_Content(R.mipmap.souper, "Menu Cantine", "Jours"));
    Main_content.add(new Main_Content(R.mipmap.abs, "Absences & Retard", "Jours"));
    Main_content.add(new Main_Content(R.mipmap.disconnect, "Déconnexion", "OUI"));
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Replace fragment to Main layout
 * @param Main_content
 */
public void updateMainLayout(Main_Content Main_content) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.container, ContentFragment.newInstance(Main_content));
    transaction.commit();

    //Ferme la navigation une fois que le fragment a été remplacé.
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}





}
```

**Class Welcome:**

```
public class Welcome extends  MainActivity {
  TextView tvView;
  private Toolbar toolbar;
  private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
  private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
  private ListView listView;
  private ArrayList<Main_Content> Main_content;
  private ListViewAdapter adapter;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WelcomeiD);

    Intent Bienvenue = getIntent();

    String Name = Bienvenue.getStringExtra("iden_text");

    tvView.setText("Bienvenue " + Name);
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Simply create a generic methods in base activity which can be called by its child activity

Comment: i think you cannot do that..make an activity including drawer fragment, and change all your activity to fragment to be included to that activity

Answer (score 0):

Make a BaseActivty which is having all the stuff of navigation drawer and extend that activity to all other activity !!